# How do I use the opt folder in apache?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to handle two domains...

If the domain is a.com use this folder for the index page

if the domain is b.com use this folder for the index page

The files or are in the opt folder

I changed sites enabled to use /opt/ directory not /var/www

Still nothing I try seems to work, it goes to /var/www and the htaccess doesn't pick up

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: I get a url not found error... I did change AllowOverride to Alll

Comment: If you didn't get 500 that means your htaccess isn't enabled and you should contact your Admin or support to enable it.